# QGis 2.8.1 Series of maps from different layers

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.8

I have many layers in one QGis-Projekt based on the same .shp-File (Community borders)  with different fields classified and displayed in each layer (Mean Income, Mean Age, Average Houshold Size ...).

I want to use the same template in the map composer for all layers. Is there is any way to export all layers at once with the same template so that I don't have to go through all the layers individually?

Comment: So you have different shp files or let's say layers. Now you want them in one shp file at the end? What is the outcome. Do you want to finally convert it into geojson or something?

Answer (score 1):

You could save the layers as a project file using different views to switch between the individual layers that are shown in the print composer.

It is possible to use the xml in the project file (by opening it in a text editor) to create individual layer files from the project file. This may be overengineering a solution to your problem though. I'd suggest saving it as a project and then switching between the layers using the layer window presets.

Remember you also don't need to do this for display purposes using default and user styles in 2.8. However, if you have different filters and fields on display, you will have to have them set as different layer.

Alternatively, you can save you print composer template as a separate file and then apply that template to each individual layer when you load them into separate project files.